# Angular 7 RXjs 6.x - How to use forkJoin (difference between `of` and `Observable.create`)

Tags: angular, rxjs6

My console.log is never call (my 2 requests is called and OK).

```
const obs1 = this.awsService.getUsers();
const obs2 = this.apiService.get('admin/user');

return forkJoin(obs1, obs2).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('res2', res);
});
```

I try unit call (console.log A and B is ok):

```
const obs1 = this.awsService.getUsers();
obs1.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('A' + res);
});

const obs2 = this.apiService.get('admin/user');
obs2.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('B' + res);
});
```

**EDIT**

My code return a observable of User[] but KO un a forkJoin:

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    const u = new User;
    u.username = user.Username;
    _users.push(u);
    return obs.next(_users);
  });
}
```

This code is OK:

```
const u1: User = new User;
u1.username = 'foo';
const u2: User = new User;
u2.username = 'foo';
const o2: Observable<User[]> = of([u1, u2]);
const fj = forkJoin(o2);
fj.subscribe(res => {
  console.log('r');
 });
 // r is ok in console
```

What difference between `of` and `Observable.create( ...  return obs.next(_users);)` ?

Comment: This should work how you have it as long as all returns are pipeable. Can you please share the essential code from the service calls?

Comment: Do your two services return any data? `forkJoin` requires all Observables to emit something at least once and complete.

Comment: yes, my two services return any data. In my second test, i have console.log A and B is ok

Comment: "data" in the sense of arrays with `length > 0`? Empty arrays/undefined/null etc. won't let the `forkJoin` Observable emit at all. Could you include the output of `console.log('A' + res);` and `console.log('B' + res);`? And, like OneLunch Man said, could you show the code of your services?

Comment: obs1 and obs2 return 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference between create and of is that of by definition completes after emitting one item.  create does not complete unless you specify it.

if you did:

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    const u = new User;
    u.username = user.Username;
    _users.push(u);
    obs.next(_users);
    obs.complete();
    return () => {}; // return value should be clean up function on completion if needed
  });
}
```

then it will work because you complete immediately after emitting.  forkJoin expects all streams to complete and will not emit until all streams have, and it will emit only with the latest value in the streams.

If you actually want all emissions, consider combineLatest instead